# Will Widget Support in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, widget, windows-mobile-6, microsoft-metro

I want to develop an application for WP7 using HTML,CSS and Javascript  something Similar to Nokia WRT(Web Widget) Will this Support in WP7? .Will the app require signing ? Can I use Metro style for WP7?

Comment: its a good question if your thinking of creating a web gadget in HTML5 perhaps but otherwise your question isnt really specific enough, applications are written in C# and Silverlight/XNA frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 (and 7.5) applications are written either using the XNA framework (for gaming style applications) or Silverlight (for "apps"). Windows Mobile 6.5 (and prior) have applications either using the compact edition of WinForms, or using embedded C++.

The current design guide for the Silverlight applications for Windows Mobile 7.x is virtually identical to that for Metro on Windows 8 (there are even a bunch of controls to help you out).

As for using a HTML/CSS/JS application; it may work in browser, but I'm not aware of any ways to (nor plans to allow) distribute apps of this type to Windows Mobile 7.x devices.

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for widgets but you may be interested in [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) as that now has beta support for WP7 and is similar to web widgets.